# SQL: How to get one of two string columns, depending if filled

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have in tables where company addresses are stored often a column with the long company name and another column with a short form. The long name is mandatory, the short form not. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[company](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[shortform] [varchar](20) NOT NULL)
```

Now in many queries I want to access the short form if filled, otherwise the long form. What is need is similar to the ISNULL function, but like a ISEMPTY function.

What I did so far is creating an universal UDF which gets the prioritized column and the other one as a fallback:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[StringPrio] (
  @prioStr varchar(max),
  @fallbackStr varchar(max))
RETURNS varchar(max)

AS BEGIN

DECLARE @returnStr varchar(max) = ''

IF @prioStr <> '' BEGIN
    SET @returnStr = @prioStr
END ELSE BEGIN
    SET @returnStr = @fallbackStr
END

RETURN @returnStr

END
```

Then I can call the function like this:

```
SELECT dbo.StringPrio(shortform,name) AS nameShort FROM company
```

But I'm not sure if this is the best solution. When I call the function inside the select block of millions of records, does it affect the query performance?
I recently updated all my engines to SQL-Server 2017. Is there something build-in?

Comment: `select coalesce(nullif(shortform,''),nullif(name,'')) as nameshort from company`

Comment: The whole point of SQL's `NULL` was to have a systematic way of treating missing or inapplicable values. It's defeated when you then choose to make a column be non-null and use some other ("in band") value to represent that the information is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to reinvent the wheel.
What you seek for can be done combining two built-in functions.

Functions are [`COALESCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`NULLIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT coalesce(nullif(shortform,''),nullif(name,'')) as nameShort FROM company
```

`NULLIF` will return NULL value if first argument is equal with the second, here `''`.

`COALESCE` can actually take any number of arguments, so it's not limited to two inputs only and returns first non-null value.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.

Can I use these functions also to do something similar: getting the shorter one of both columns? So if shortname is filled and shorter than name, return shortname. Otherwise return name.

Comment: This would require a `CASE` statement with `LEN` function to perform an IF-like logic. This is for another question though. Look it up, I'm sure you will be able to find the answer you're looking for using docs.